# How do I show the values of an array I'm calling from an API in html?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is the interface of the json I get from the API.

```
        export interface Subclass {
            url: string;
            name: string;
        }
        export interface TheClass {
            index: string;
            name: string;
            hit_die: number;
            subclasses: Subclass[];
            url: string;
        }
```

```
{"_id":"5ecc9ace0b1bb138c5431c12","index":"rogue","name":"Rogue","hit_die":8,"subclasses":[{"url":"/api/subclasses/thief","name":"Thief"}],"url":"/api/classes/rogue"}
```

Following code is where I subscribe to the API

```
  setFieldsClass(value: string){
    this.OnlineAPIService.getClasses(value).subscribe(data=>{
      this.TheClass = data;
```

Where GetClasses is the following

```
 getClasses(value: string){
    return this.client.get<TheClass>("http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/classes/"+value);
  }
```

```
<table *ngIf="TheClass">

        <tr>

            <th>name</th>
            <th>hit_die</th>
            <th>subclasses</th>
            <th>url</th>
        </tr>
        <tr  style="text-align:center">

            <td>{{TheClass.name}}</td>
            <td>{{TheClass.hit_die}}</td>
            <td>{{TheClass.subclasses}}</td>
            <td>{{TheClass.url}}</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Now it will show me the name, hit die and url just fine but for the subclasses it will say Object object. How can I show the values of this array, specifically Name?
[image: Example]

Comment: We're going to need the definition of `Subclass`, a JSON example, and a description of what you want to show to be able to help you.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I have given a JSON example and more info

Comment: Normally I would not use the Name of a class as a variable name to an instance if the same Class. That causes confusions. That being said, you need to render the subclasses separately

Comment: How do you want to display `subclasses` ? as a list, If so use `*ngFor` on a `li` tag (e.g `<li *ngFor="let subclass of subclasses">{{subclass.name}}</li>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to show the names of the subclasses would be to use [`ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) to loop over them and display their names:

```
<td>
    <div *ngFor="let sc of TheClass.subclasses">{{ sc.name }}</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will solve it. **Note that I am using Bootstrap**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e1ushq